# how to use outside var/statement inside another function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

How and what are the other ways to this

```
function myFun2(){    
var e = 10 * x;
var f = 20 * x;
}
var array = [1,2,3]
array.forEach(function(x){
 myFun2;
 e + f ;
})
```

or

```
var e = 10 * x;
var f = 20 * x;
var array = [1,2,3]
array.forEach(function(x){
 e + f ;
})
```

I want to get the output of `e + f`, what are the different ways to do this ?

Comment: What are `myFun2;` and `e + f;` supposed to do? Return the values from a function....

Comment: You can't because scope is limited to the function.

Comment: any ways to do this ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your problem that you think cannot be solve by traditional parameter passing and return values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var  par , M ;
function myFun(e){
  par = 100 ;
     //M = par - e ;
  M = par - 10 ;
 }
var sms = [1,2,3];
sms.forEach(function(e) {
 myFun(e);
    e=M
    console.log(""+M)
    });
```

You could do something like this by making e and f variables global variables

```js
var e=0;
var f=0;
function myFun2(x){    
 e= 10 * x;
 f= 20 * x;
}
array = [1,2,3]
array.forEach(function(x){
 myFun2(x);
 console.log(e + f) ;
})
```

Comment: if I declare `e = 10` and `f=20` as a global , will it work ?

Comment: yes it will work,you can check in the same working snippet as shown above

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAX85MC8E17Q check this still have prblm

Comment: I have inserted the code snippet which you had provided in the link and changed it slightly by removing the declarations of par and M from inside the function.if you declare the variables again inside the function that variable will become a local variable and it will manipulated instead of the global variable

Comment: yes the first code snippet in my post is your actual code with some changes which will work

Comment: glad it helped :),please mark it as the answer ,to help people searching for the answer on a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what exactly you are trying to do, but seems like you want to call `myFun2` for each value of array and get the result.

```
function myFun2(x){
  var e = 10 * x;
  var f = 20 * x;
  return +e + +f;
}
array = [1,2,3]
array.forEach(function(x){
  var result = myFun2(x);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [ 1,2,3 ]; 
func1(x);

function func1(params) {
  for (i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
   var sum=func2(x);
alert(sum);
  }
}

function func2(y) {
var e=y*10:
var f=y*20:
return e+f;
  }
```

Comment: code only answers is not good answers as they fail to explain what the problem was and how this resolves it. @srinivas